# Sending secured REST API request in react native

Tags: react-native

- I am using 'fetch' method of React Native to call REST API. How can we send the request to secured API (URL start with 'https') in React native?

Comment: Change the URL in the fetch method. `const request = new Request('https://example.com', {method: 'POST', body: '{"foo": "bar"}'});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Parameter**

```
var params = 'user_id=' + res.user_id
params += '&first_name=' + firstName
```

**Request**

Content-Type -  set as per your requirement

```
fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         'Authorization': token,
      },
      body: params 
  })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) => {
     console.log("RESPONSE:- ", json)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
     console.log("ERROR WEB:- ", err)
  })
```